# Uniquely identifying anonymous method with parameters of Func body

Tags: .net, caching, expression, anonymous, func

I'm trying to write some magic code for handling caching that may or may not be possible. Basically, the idea is to have a CacheManager class with a static method which accepts an Func to execute as a parameter. In the static method's body, it would be able to execute that Func and cache the results using a cache key that uniquely identifies the internals of that Func passed (an anonymous method with 0 or more parameters). Subsequent calls to that static method with the same arguments provided would result in the same cache key and return the cached results.

I need a way of uniquely identifying the anonymous function that is passed in.

***Edit:** Expression provided the answer once I adjusted the anonymous function syntax.*

I'm worried about the performance impact of having to compile the expression at run-time. Given this is an attempt to support caching for performance it'd be silly for the compile to take any significant amount of time. Any thoughts?

**Basic repository for testing:**

```
public class Product
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ProductRepository
{
    private List<Product> products { get; set; }

    public ProductRepository()
    {
        products = new List<Product>() { new Product() { ID = 1, Name = "Blue Lightsaber" }, new Product() { ID = 2, Name = "Green Lightsaber" }, new Product() { ID = 3, Name = "Red Lightsaber" } };
    }

    public Product GetByID(int productID)
    {
        return products.SingleOrDefault(p => p.ID == productID);
    }
}
```

**CacheManager:**

```
public class CacheManager
{
    public static TResult Get<TResult>(Expression<Func<TResult>> factory)
    {
        if (factory == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("factory");

        var methodCallExpression = factory.Body as MethodCallExpression;
        if (methodCallExpression == null) throw new ArgumentException("factory must contain a single MethodCallExpression.");

        string cacheKey = "|Repository:" + methodCallExpression.Method.DeclaringType.FullName + "|Method:" + methodCallExpression.Method.Name + "|Args";
        foreach (var arg in methodCallExpression.Arguments)
        {
            cacheKey += ":" + (arg is ConstantExpression ? ((ConstantExpression)arg).Value : Expression.Lambda(arg).Compile().DynamicInvoke());
        }

        if (HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheKey] == null)
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheKey] = factory.Compile().Invoke();
        }
        return (TResult)HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheKey];
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
ProductRepository productRepository = new ProductRepository();
int productID = 1;
Product product;

// From repo
product = CacheManager.Get<Product>(() => productRepository.GetByID(1));

// From cache
product = CacheManager.Get<Product>(() => productRepository.GetByID(productID));
```

Comment: Is the body of the action restricted in any way? Or could it be basically any arbitrary code?

Comment: That was going to be my next problem... is it even possible to enforce anything there?? I could probably put a restriction on the TInstance type. It would be nice to enforce that the Action body was a single assignment statement to my `out` argument to reduce the chance of something volatile being passed as the Action (assuming that is the syntax required if a final solution is achieved).

Comment: You can't enforce it at compile time, you can only enforce it at runtime with the help of expressions. One thought: Why the strange syntax with assigning to the variable and having the same one as an out parameter? Why not simply use a `Func<TRepository, TResult>` and change `GetValue` to this signature: `TResult GetValue<TRepository, TResult>(TRepository repository, Func<TRepository, TResult> valueFactory)`? This would actually work, your current code wouldn't.

Comment: The current code actually does correctly assign a value and works but I'll agree it is strange. I'll have a look at your suggestion of using Func and update my question shortly. It is actually something I had considered, but I didn't explore it fully. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I've updated my question with your suggestions. Looks much nicer. I still have the same problem though. How to get a cache key from the `Func<TRepository, TResult>` argument? If I wrap it in an `Expression` I'd get access to the Body, but I can't pass the Func as the Body because "A lamba expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an Expression tree". Plus, even if I could wrap it I'd need to call Compile() on the `Expression` before invoking it; which I imagine has some overhead making it less performant (although it'd only need to compile on cache miss). Thoughts?

Comment: Don't use a statement body. Use this: `(productsRepositoryInstance) => productsRepositoryInstance.GetByID(1)`. I think you can't get around calling `Compile` if you don't want to compare IL code to get your cache-key. However, using the IL code could be an alternative: When you are not using an expression, you cann call `Method.GetMethodBody().GetILasByteArray()` on the delegate. I guess that byte array could be used as the key. However, I am not sure how performant it is to have a key of that size.

Comment: Thanks again. I've updated the question with code that achieves the job and doesn't need to compile the Expression to IL unless the cache key is a cache miss. Any outstanding issues you see? What do you think about caching the compiled Func? Given how small the Expression body will be and how the Expression only needs compiling on cache misses, the overhead is probably insignificant. Any more exception handling I could throw in there? Particularly around the casting of the Expression to a MethodCallExpression? Or just let the runtime throw its own exception? Cheers!

Comment: Looks good. Two more points to consider: (1) You should check that the MethodCallExpression is actually calling the method on the repository that is passed in as a parameter to the delegate (2) `(arg as ConstantExpression).Value` will throw a `NullReferenceException` if `arg` is not a `ConstantExpression`. Code that throws a `NullReferenceException` is considered buggy. It should throw an `ArgumentException` telling the caller that all parameters must be constants. Which, by the way, seems like an odd requirement. What about `r => r.GetByID(id)`?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I misunderstood the definition of ConstantExpression. I'll add the check on instance being passed in and also think about how to get the argument value another way.

Comment: I solved issue 1 mentioned above by removing the repository parameter all together. Issue 2 is a little bit tricky because I need to accomodate for expressions as parameters in the anonymous method. I've attempted a solution and it works when passing constants and variables as shown in the Usage code. The usage is quite succinct now. I don't think I'm ever going to be able to fully lock down and restrict what is passed in for the Expression so I'll just try and do the best checking I can.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you would like to do something like [Memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization). Memoization is a method of storing results that have already been computed, which seems to be your requirement.

A better way to do this is to create a new function object that differs from the original in that it will store the results in a Dictionary and perform lookups on the parameters supplied. This new function will handle the caching, and will add to the cache in the case of a miss.

This class will create memoized versions of functions of one argument:

```
public static class memofactory
{
    public static Func<In, Out> Memoize<In, Out>(Func<In, Out> BaseFunction)
    {
        Dictionary<In,Out> ResultsDictionary = new Dictionary<In, Out>();

        return Input =>
            {
                Out rval;
                try
                {
                    rval = ResultsDictionary[Input];
                    Console.WriteLine("Cache hit"); // tracing message
                }
                catch (KeyNotFoundException)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Cache miss"); // tracing message
                    rval = BaseFunction(Input);
                    ResultsDictionary[Input] = rval;
                }
                return rval;
            };
    }
}
```

The usage, based on your example is:

```
        ProductRepository productRepository = new ProductRepository();
        int productID = 1;
        Product product;

        Func<int, Product> MemoizedGetById = memofactory.Memoize<int, Product>(productRepository.GetByID);

        // From repo
        product = MemoizedGetById(1);

        // From cache
        product = MemoizedGetById(productID);
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, I've never heard of the Memoize concept. Seems similar to what I'm after. I guess the limitation in your sample is that it can only handle Func input with one parameter, though you could make many overrides of Memoize accepting up to In9 parameters.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Yes, you would have to override Memoize to handle more parameters, and would have to package up the parameters into a tuple or struct to use as keys to the dictionary. If my answer solved your problem, please accept it, if there is anything I can make more clear let me know.